# influx db v2.5 API

Tags: json, influxdb, curl-commandline

How to make the curl command return output in JSON format for POST request,at present I get the csv format even if --header "Accept: application/json" ,the older version worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Could you try appending pretty=true to the URL so to enable pretty-printed JSON output? e.g.

```
curl -G 'http://localhost:8086/query?pretty=true'
```

See more info [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/enterprise_influxdb/v1.10/guides/query_data/#query-data-with-influxql).